# linear subspace of projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What is a $k$-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb{P}^n=$Proj $k[x_0,...,x_n]$?

Is it a subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^k$ or do I need something else?

Comment: You need it to be linear, i.e., the homogeneous ideal is generated by its degree 1 piece.

Comment: @user10354138 Does this mean I have $V(\mathfrak{a})$ with $\mathfrak{a}=(f_1,...,f_d)$, f_i homogeneous and of degree 1 or what do you mean with degree 1 piece?

Comment: Yes (once you apply noetherian condition).  $\mathfrak{a}=\langle\mathfrak{a}\cap(kx_0\oplus\dots\oplus kx_n))\rangle$ (and you mean $\operatorname{Proj} k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ not $\operatorname{Proj} k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$).

Comment: I think you can also think about it like this: $k[x_0, \ldots, x_n] = \operatorname{Sym}(V)$, where $V = k^{n+1}$ is an $(n+1)$-dimensional vector space. An $m$-dimensional linear subspace $Y$ is one such that there is an $(m+1)$-dimensional subspace $W$ of $V$ such that $Y = \operatorname{Proj}(\operatorname{Sym}(W))$.